# Tokenize text but keep compund hyphenated words together

Tags: python, regex, nlp

I am trying to clean up text using a pre-processing function. I want to remove all non-alpha characters such as punctuation and digits, but I would like to retain compound words that use a dash without splitting them (e.g. pre-tender, pre-construction).

```
def preprocess(text):
  #remove punctuation
  text = re.sub('\b[A-Za-z]+(?:-+[A-Za-z]+)+\b', '-', text)
  text = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]', ' ', text)
  text = text.split()
  text = " ".join(text)
  return text
```

For instance, the original text:

```
"Attended pre-tender meetings"
```

should be split into

```
['attended', 'pre-tender', 'meeting']
```

rather than

```
['attended', 'pre', 'tender', 'meeting']
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove all non-alpha characters but `-` between letters, you can use

```
[\W\d_](?<![^\W\d_]-(?=[^\W\d_]))
```

ASCII only equivalent:

```
[^A-Za-z](?<![A-Za-z]-(?=[A-Za-z]))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mDri9b/1). *Details*:

- `[\W\d_]` - any non-letter
- `(?<![^\W\d_]-(?=[^\W\d_]))` - a negative lookbehind that fails the match if there is a letter and a `-` immediately to the left, and right after `-`, there is any letter (checked with the `(?=[^\W\d_])` positive lookahead).

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/RPh8tQ):

```py
import re

def preprocess(text):
  #remove all non-alpha characters but - between letters
  text = re.sub(r'[\W\d_](?<![^\W\d_]-(?=[^\W\d_]))', r' ', text)
  return " ".join(text.split())

print(preprocess("Attended pre-tender, etc meetings."))
# => Attended pre-tender etc meetings
```

Answer (score 1):

The *string* module has constant strings *punctuation* and *digits*.

However, a hyphen is considered to be a punctuation character. Therefore, without the aid of RE, you could do this:

```
from string import punctuation, digits

s = 'Attended pre-tender meetings'

t = s.strip(punctuation.replace('-', '')+digits).split()

print(t)
```

**Output:**

```
['Attended', 'pre-tender', 'meetings']
```